# Why isn't my code correctly identifying only prime numbers?

Tags: r

I can't figure out why the code below produces a vector with some non-prime numbers as well.

```r
i <- (3)
v1 <- (2)
v2 <- c()

while (i < 13195)
{
    v1 <- c(v1,i)
#The IF statement below is intended to identify only primes that are factors of 13195, but some none primes such as 2639 appeared in the vector 'v2'
    if (((i/v1) != round(i/v1)) & ((13195/i) == round(13195/i)))
    {
        v2 <- c(v2, i)
        i <- i+1
    }
    else
    {
        i <- i+1
    }
}
```

Comment: One shortcoming is, `v1` is a vector so `1/v1` is actually a vectorized divison, more like `1/1, 1/2, 1/3` and `if` is not a vectorized function and only compares on the basis of first element

Comment: Another shortcoming is the whole "identify primes that are a factor of 13195" part. No primes are a factor of 13195 by definition, as a prime number only factors into itself and 1. Are you trying to find primes or numbers that are a multiple of 13195?

Comment: Are you basing this on a known algorithm? I've just never seen round() used in finding primes. What am I missing?

Comment: Well prime numbers don't have any factors other than themselves and 1 so if you divide a number by each previous numbers starting from 2 and the result of all the divisions is a non whole number then using != round() will reveal it and therefore it will be a prime number. If at least one of the numbers resulting from the division is a whole number than it is not a prime number and !=round() of that number won't be TRUE. That was the idea at least, but I suspect my logic is flawed.

Comment: @Keo Execute `warnings()`  at the end of your snippet. The warnings will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your logic is fine. The problem I see is that the `if` statement has a structure of `if(vector & scalar)` which may mess things up. You may want to change it to

```
if (all((i/v1) != round(i/v1)) & ...
```

Another problem is that each iteration has `i` added to `v1` prior to the conditional. So the last element of `(i/v1) != round(i/v1)` is always going to evaluate `False`, because the last element of `v1` is `i` and `i/i != round(i/i)` will be `False`. This will render the conditional always `False`. The solution is to update `i <- i + 1` after appending the old `i` to v1.

Here is updated code:

```
i<-2
v1<-c()
v2<-c()

while (i<13195) {
  v1<-c(v1,i)
  i<-i+1
  
  if (all((i/v1) != round(i/v1)) & ((13195/i)==round(13195/i))){
    v2<-c(v2, i)
  }
  
}
```